# CSS Left : 50% puts element to the edge of the screen

Tags: html, css, scaling

I'm trying to center a button on my website, so I tried left : 50% to get it to the middle of the screen, but for some reason it brings it all the way to the right side of the screen. Here's the code:

```
#ContactButton {
    font-size: 20px;
    border: none;
    width : 120px;
    position : relative;
    height: 30px;
    font-weight: 500;
    border-radius: 30px;
    left : 50%;
}
```

Comment: Use one of these methods to center your button, don't use `left: 50%` https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/ ... Check the "Flexbox" solution, that should work for you.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways. On the button itself, you can just use `margin: 0 auto;`.

Or you could maybe just use `text-align: center` on the button's container.

Or, for example, you could use flexbox on the buttons container:

```
.container{
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
}
```

And there are several other possibilities. Check the link @cloned gave you on his comment.

Comment: Thanks for the response, whenever I use any of those methods, it still puts it to the top right of the screen. I think it may be because I'm currently on a laptop with a small screen.

Comment: Mmm, do not mix those methods with your original code. Also, take a closer look at the button's container. Maybe the issue is there. Use colored backgrounds to temporarily highlight elements areas, or just use you browser's console/dev tools and check bot the button and its container(s).